# Update values (find and replace)

Tags: perl, shell

I need to compare and replace a value in two files.  I have two flat files of approximately 1000+ employee records. The goal is to update the phone number using the employee ID in first column from list UPDATE to RECORD.  I have written something...

**UPDATE RECORDS**

```
E0000013 8327733241X7131030001
E0011183 8327731234
E0000231 8327731873
E0000453 8321832322
E0003421 8328722221
E0000398 8327739741X1112223333
```

**SAMPLE MADEUP RECORD - NOT REAL NAMES OR NUMBERS**

```
E0000013 MARY JACKSON 1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 7131030001X7131030001 FL21
E0011187 JANE DOE     1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 7131030003            FL17
E0000231 JUANITTA     1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 7131030002            FL38
E0000453 ETHA MACK    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 7131030004            FL31
E0000542 EDDIE JOE    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 7131030009            FL32
E0003421 FRANCIS Y    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 7131030008            FL33
E0000398 ZAYLA YEN    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 7131030018            FL41
```

**CODE**

*Please find the updated code in my answer. I am trying to remove a bug that is shifting some of my values.  I am not trying to have anyone write the code for me, but highlight my mistakes and offer good advise.*

## EXPECTED OUTCOME

```
E0000013 MARY JACKSON 1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8327733241X7131030001 FL21
E0011187 JANE DOE     1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8327731234            FL17     
E0000231 JUANITTA     1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8327731873            FL38
E0000453 ETHA MACK    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8321832322            FL31
E0000542 EDDIE JOE    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8321834343            FL32
E0003421 FRANCIS Y    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8328722221            FL33
E0000398 ZAYLA YEN    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8327739741X1112223333 FL41
```

**ACTUAL-OUTPUT**
As you may see, the actual output is shifting my data to the right for Mary Jackson and . How can I get rid of the spaces and maintain the floor values from shifting?

```
E0000013 MARY JACKSON 1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8327733241X7131030001            FL21
E0011187 JANE DOE     1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 7131030003            FL17
E0000231 JUANITTA     1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8327731873            FL38
E0000453 ETHA MACK    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8321832322            FL31
E0000542 EDDIE JOE    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8321834343            FL32
E0003421 FRANCIS Y    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8328722221            FL33
E0000398 ZAYLA YEN    1111FANNINS ST HOUSTON TX 77004 8327739741X1112223333            FL41
```

Comment: I think you need a lot more experience before you can solve this yourself, or even to understand a solution if it was written for you. The biggest problem I can see is that you can't just `split` each line on spaces, as you would get the second and third fields as `MARY` and `JACKSON` instead of combining them as a complete name. I think you should use `unpack`, but I also think you have chosen too difficult a task to start with. Stack Overflow isn't about providing complete programs, and even if I was to write one for you it wouldn't help you learn, and you would soon be needing more help.

Comment: If my first name were James, you could ping me on Lynx and I could give you a hand.

Comment: Also the #'s for Jane and Eddie don't have a match in your updates, so your expected outcome could not be achieved with your current input.

Comment: I am actually looking for assistance with either substitution or of the string in a for in my code, I am just comparing the E0* and also PHONE and attempting to replace.  I have been reading and seems not to understand.  How would you do it?

Comment: You could find the 'current' phone number with:  `m/(\w+)\W+\w+$/`  That will save the found phone number in `$1`, which could then be used in a substitution with:  `s/$1/$new_number/;`

Comment: I am seeking more help to improve on my code.  Please run the data code and you will notice that it is adding an extra space.  I am seeking assistance on ways to remove the extra space....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This is how I solved this and it worked as expected, thanks everyone for looking or comments***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %employeehash;

open my $RECORD,'<','/home/maryh/Documents/employee.txt' || die $!;
open my $UPDATE,'<','/home/maryh/Documents/updatedphone.txt' || die $!;
open my $MODIFIED,'>','/home/maryh/Documents/xphone.txt' || die $!;


while (<$UPDATE>) {

   my ($emp_id, $phone) = split /\s+/;

   $employeehash{$emp_id} = $phone;

}
while(<$RECORD>) {

   chomp(my $line = $_);
   my $emp_id = substr($line,0,8);
   my $phone = substr( $line ,54,10);
   $emp_id =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
   $phone =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

 if (exists $employeehash{$emp_id} ) {

      $emp_id = $employeehash{$emp_id};
      $emp_id =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; 
      substr($line,54,21) =~ s/$phone/$emp_id/; 
      print "[$phone] got change to [$emp_id]\n"; 

  }

print $MODIFIED "$line\n" ; 

}

close $MODIFIED;
close $UPDATE;
close $RECORD;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to point out that your example code is riddled with errors that are very obvious to me, and I have only been perling for about 3 months.

Maybe read a [free book](https://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/) or a [llama book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449303587).

As to your source code it is not going to work like that. I went ahead and threw something together to do what you wanted, but I recommend that you learn more about perl so you can solve problems like these more easily.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
open $newnums_fh, '<', '/home/job/newfile.txt' or die $!;
open $records_fh, '<', '/home/job/records.txt' or die $!;
open $newrecords_fh, '>', '/home/job/records_out.txt' or die $!;
while(<$newnums_fh>) {
    my @line = split(/\s+/, $_);
    my $employee_id = shift @line;
    my $employee_phone = pop @line;
    $phonenums{ $employee_id } = $employee_phone;
}
close($newnums_fh);
while(<$records_fh>) {
    my @line = split(/\s+/, $_);
    my $employee_id = shift @line;
    if(exists $phonenums{ $employee_id} ) {
        my $new_phone = $phonenums{ $employee_id };
        unshift @line, $employee_id;
        my $last_value = pop @line;
        my $old_phone = pop @line;
        push @line, $new_phone;
        push @line, $last_value;
        if(scalar @line == 9) {
            print $newrecords_fh join("\t", @line) . "\n";
        } elsif(scalar @line == 10) {
            print $newrecords_fh shift @line; #employee ID
            print $newrecords_fh "\t" . shift @line; #first name
            print $newrecords_fh ' ' . shift @line; #second name
            print $newrecords_fh "\t";
            print $newrecords_fh join("\t", @line) . "\n";
        } else {
            warn "Line is the wrong size! going to skip the entry!\n";
        }
    } else {
        next;
    }
}
```